# Working with the data in a file csv

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

someone can give me some advice?

I'm developing an app.

I have a file that will be loaded with data every day .. 
these data once they are uploaded to the files should be deleted after 15 days ...

What do you recommend?

A function that takes the current date and compares it with the one in which they were entered data?

Or a timer function that deletes files after 15 days by the insertion?

In both cases, I have no more idea how to hook the date the data entered daily

What do you say? 
Help me thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything at this point? Care to share with us what you have tried?

Comment: provide some code or something as a example in order to receive help.

Comment: I honestly have not tried. 
Why I have no idea which solution to try .. And most of all how to do it

Comment: You should include a create date field when you store the data, and then create a script that runs once a day and clears out data that's older than 15 days.